# Calling a method with parameters on managed bean with EL in XPages

Tags: jsf, xpages, el

I have a managed bean with I can call via SSJS in the following way:

```
xptI18NBean.getValue("customer.cardNumber")
```

However I would like to use EL instead but I do not manage to find the EL equivalent.

I tried

```
${xptI18NBean.value(customer.cardNumber)}
```

But then I get the error message:
xptI18NBean.value(customer.cardNumber)
Påträffade "(", en av ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", "?"] förväntades
Encountered "(" at line 1, column 20. Was expecting one of: "}" ... "." ... ">" ... "gt" ... "<" ... "lt" ... "==" ... "eq" ... "<=" ... "le" ... ">=" ... "ge" ... "!=" ... "ne" ... "[" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "div" ... "%" ... "mod" ... "and" ... "&&" ... "or" ... "||" ... "?" ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer is that the version of EL that XPages uses doesn't support method parameters.

That said, the sort of bean you have there seems like it either already implements `DataObject` or is a prime candidate to do so. If the bean implements `DataObject`, you could do `${xptI18NBean['customer.cardNumber']}`, which would then resolve to be the same call as in SSJS there.

Additionally, the [XPages Jakarta EE project](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.xsp.jakartaee) includes an opt-in ability to use EL 3, which *does* support method parameters.

Comment: I get the error message Error getting property 'customer.cardNumber' from bean of type org.acme.myproject.lang.beans.XPTI18NBean . Any idea why that is?

Comment: I copied the code from the XPages Toolkit project...

Comment: Do you mean you got that when you switch to `${xptI18NBean['customer.cardNumber']}`? That would happen if `xptI18NBean` doesn't implement `DataObject` or `Map`. Without one of those interfaces, it'll try to resolve `'customer.cardNumber'` to a getter name, which won't work. Looking at the implementation from the XPages Toolkit, it doesn't implement one of those, so that makes sense.

Comment: If you want to use EL for this purpose, you should make that class (or a similar one) implement one of those interfaces - I particularly like `DataObject` for this sort of thing, since it's simple. Alternatively, you could fall back to SSJS for this purpose, which I do from time to time.